# Issues with task in Capistrano deploy.rb file

Tags: ruby, linux, deployment, capistrano

I have the following in my deploy.rb file that I have taken from [this tutorial](http://theme.fm/2011/09/deploying-wordpress-with-capistrano-part-2-staging-servers-tagging-database-security-2213/) and everything works exactly as it should with the exception of the `touch` command.

Does anyone have any idea why this may not be working?

```
set :application, "your-application-name"
set :repository, "git@github.com:you/your-project.git"
set :scm, :git
set :deploy_to, "/home/path/to/project/"
set :use_sudo, false

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :copy_exclude, [".git", ".DS_Store", ".gitignore", ".gitmodules"]

server "example.org", :app

namespace :myproject do
    task :symlink, :roles => :app do
        run "ln -nfs #{shared_path}/uploads #{release_path}/application/wp-content/uploads"
        run "touch #{release_path}/env_production"
    end
end

after "deploy:create_symlink", ":after_deploy"
```

**Output of cap deploy**

```
 * executing `deploy'
 * executing `deploy:update'
** transaction: start
 * executing `deploy:update_code'
   updating the cached checkout on all servers
   executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:jeffreynolte/Testing-WP-Workflow.git HEAD"
 * executing "if [ -d /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/shared/cached-copy ]; then cd /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/shared/cached-copy && git fetch -q origin && git fetch --tags -q origin && git reset -q --hard 8c10e1f459dc78a127681362386bb84d5fbf3662 && git clean -q -d -x -f; else git clone -q git@github.com:jeffreynolte/Testing-WP-Workflow.git /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/shared/cached-copy && cd /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/shared/cached-copy && git checkout -q -b deploy 8c10e1f459dc78a127681362386bb84d5fbf3662; fi"
   servers: ["domain.com"]
   [domain.com] executing command
   command finished in 3905ms
   copying the cached version to /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/releases/20121026041737
 * executing "rsync -lrpt --exclude=\".git\" --exclude=\".DS_Store\" --exclude=\".gitignore\" --exclude=\".gitmodules\" /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/shared/cached-copy/ /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/releases/20121026041737 && (echo 8c10e1f459dc78a127681362386bb84d5fbf3662 > /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/releases/20121026041737/REVISION)"
   servers: ["domain.com"]
   [domain.com] executing command
   command finished in 577ms
 * executing `deploy:finalize_update'
 * executing "chmod -R g+w /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/releases/20121026041737"
   servers: ["domain.com"]
   [domain.com] executing command
   command finished in 51ms
 * executing `deploy:symlink'
 * executing "rm -f /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/current && ln -s /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/releases/20121026041737 /var/www/domain.com/subdomains/wp-workflow/current"
   servers: ["domain.com"]
   [domain.com] executing command
   command finished in 45ms
** transaction: commit
```

Comment: According to the above config, the env_production file should be created in the `/home/path/to/project/releases/<date_time_stamp_of_relase>` folder, right? Is the env_production file not present in that folder?

Comment: Hi @PrakashMurthy Thanks for your reply. The file is not present there or anywhere on the server.

Comment: What's the exact value for `release_path` variable on the server for the most recent deploy?

Comment: HI @PrakashMurthy - I have tried everything at this point.  It just seems the callback is not running after deploy:symlink.  Any ideas?

Comment: Have you sanity checked the permissions on `#{release_path}` to make sure it isn't read only for whatever reason?

Comment: HI @cbmanica - Thanks for your reply. I have checked the permissions. Even if wouldn't I get an error when capistrano runs?  Everything else is running perfectly fine except for the deploy:symlink callback.

Comment: At first glance everything looks ok. I suggest you try the following for debugging: 1. check the cap output to make sure 'deploy:symlink' is executed. 2. check the output that the 'myproject:symlink' task is executed. 3. check the output for any errors when running the *touch* command

Comment: @jnolte The code you shown above looks totally fine. There is more data needed. Please provide your whole Capistrano output for running `cap deploy` and `cap myproject:symlink` also `cap -v`.

Comment: Thanks all for your feedback. I have added the output above to see if that can lend some insight.

Answer (score 3):

In current Capistrano versions the default task `deploy:symlink` is deprecated and has been replaced by `deploy:create_symlink`

To make it work, change your last line to:

```
after "deploy:create_symlink", "myproject:symlink"
```

See [capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb line 294 and following](https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/blob/master/lib/capistrano/recipes/deploy.rb#L294). You should have seen a deprecation warning in the Capistrano output. To make the Capistrano output more readable I heavily recommend the [capistrano_colors gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/capistrano_colors).

Comment: Hi @aef - I have tried this before without any luck.  I have even use my code on some other callbacks with no luck. It is like it gets completely ignored. Any ideas?

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem, what Capistrano version do you use? If it's not the latest, try updating it with `gem install capistrano`

Comment: I am using the latest version.

Comment: @jnolte Please tell me the output of `cap --version`. The most current version should definately not execute the `deploy:symlink` task, which seems to happen according to your log: `* executing `deploy:symlink'`. I suspect that the executable you are calling is not from the latest installed gem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem, and after some hair pulling, I figured that my problem was on railsless-deploy gem. Updating it to the version 1.1.0 made everything work fine.